# In Lisa the AI package for common list when I wish the rules to fire only once

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

I'm using SBCL with the LISA package. When I run a procedure with several rules an endless loop starts, because my rules fire more than once. How can I control this wrong behaviour ?

Here is the simple rule with one fact. I suppose that the modification of the fact "Italy" triggers the rule again and so on. Is there a way out ?

```
(in-package mbg)

(setf Italy 
  (make-instance 'COUNTRY 'name 'Italy 'population 60 
          'area 'west 'language 'Italian 'gdp 2100 'debt 2700 
          'industry '( metal mechanical textile petrochem fashion 
           tourism)
          'continent 'Europe))

(pushnew 'Italy countries)

(assert-instance mbg::Italy)

(in-package lisa-user)

(defrule testab (:salience 0)
  (?country (mbg::country 
              (mbg::name ?name)
              (mbg::debt ?debt)
              (mbg::gdp  ?gdp))
  (test (and (> ?gdp 2000.) (> ?debt 1000.))))
  =>
  (modify ?country (mbg::inflation  15))
  (print ?name))

     
(defclass COUNTRY ()
   ((name :initform 'name :initarg name :accessor name)
    (population :initform 0 :initarg population :accessor population)
    (area   :initform 'area :initarg area :accessor area)
    (language :initform 'language :initarg language :accessor language)
    (gdp    :initform 'gdp  :initarg gdp :accessor gdp)
    (debt :initform 'debt :initarg debt :accessor debt)
    (inflation :initform 0  :initarg inflation :accessor inflation)
    (discount-rate :initform nil :initarg discount-rate :accessor 
   discount-rate)
    (industry :initform 'industry :initarg industry :accessor industry)
    (continent :initform 'continent :initarg continent :accessor 
   continent)))
```

Comment: you probably wrote a recursive rule

Comment: Please show a minimal reproducible example of such a procedure.  As is, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: Yes I think you're right coredump. I modified the posted question to add the simple procedure i try to run.

Comment: What is the 'COUNTRY' class definition?

Comment: Thank you Robert I posted the class COUNTRY definition.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate your problem and I don't know much about LISA but the immediate solution I see is to add a guard in your rule that checks the inflation, so that once the instance is modified, the rule no longer applies. That's the change I made:

```
(defrule testab (:salience 0)
  (?country (country 
             (name ?name)
             (debt ?debt)
             (gdp  ?gdp)
             (inflation ?inflation))
  (test (and (> ?gdp 2000.) (> ?debt 1000.) (= ?inflation 0))))
  =>
  (modify ?country (inflation  15))
  (print ?name))
```

Comment: Thank you coredump, bu even with your change the system goes to an endless loop. There could possibly be a bug in the program. I tried all tricks to fix this strange behaviour. After the first firing of the rule the RHS is changed and the rule shouldn't fire again. But it does !!

Comment: @ponipei that fixed the issue on my machine so I can't really know why there is something different on yours. If you restart your environment from scratch with the new version does it still loop endlessly?

Comment: yes it does !! Coredump can I ask you if you are working in SBCL and have loaded the LISA package and are you working inside the LISA-USER package ?

Comment: @ponipei That's what I did, in your question you defined another package "mbg" but for my tests I just wrote everything in LISA-USER.

Comment: solved !!! Thank you so much @coredump. I reinitialised everything and corrected an error concerning parenteses. It is now working correctly also chaining different rules, which was my target. Thank you.